# Convergence of binomial to normal

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Problem: Let $X_n \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,p_n) $ where $p_n \xrightarrow{} 0$ and $np_n \xrightarrow{} \infty$. What I need to show is that

$$\frac{X_n - np_n}{\sqrt{np_n}} \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1) \text{ as } n\xrightarrow{} \infty.$$
**My thoughts:** My first thought was to set 
$$Y_n=\frac{X_n - np_n}{\sqrt{np_n}}$$
and investigate $P(Y_n=k) = p_{X_n}(\sqrt{np_n}k + np_n) $ as $n$ goes to infinity, but this led to very messy calculations so I don't know if it is the right approach. My second attempt was with Central Limit Theorem, rewriting $X_n$ as a sum of Bernoulli random variables, $X_n = Z_1 + \dots + Z_n$, $Z_n \sim \operatorname{Be}(p_n)$. The expectation and variance of each $Z_i$ is dependent on $n$ in that case. Will that violate any assumptions in CLT?

I prefer working out these kind of questions from definition rather than using a theorem and previous results, so if anyone can show me that I would be very grateful!

Thanks.

Comment: Your second attempt is definitely on the right track. For the first one, do you mean $k$ to be an integer? Because obviously that's not right. Plus, even if you allow $k$ to be any real number, you still get into trouble because the probability goes to zero. You need to be careful in going from a discrete to a continuous distribution.

Comment: Hm.. true, didn't think of that. How would one approach this question if one was not allowed to use CLT to solve it?

Comment: The reason why this doesn't yield instantly to the most usual form of the central limit theorem is that these are not identically distributed, since $p_n$ depends on $n$.  And the fact that $np_n\to\infty$ matters.  One approach might be to try to prove this the same way the central limit theorem is proved, by looking at the limit of the sequence of characteristic functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But for every $n$, all $Z_i$ are indentically distributed?

Comment: Why $\sqrt{np_n}$ in demoninator and not $ \sqrt{var(X_n)} = \sqrt{np_n(1-p_n)} $?  Shouldn't $Y_n = \frac{(X_n - \bar{X_n})}{\sqrt{var(X_n)}} \sim N(0,1)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this in two steps. First take $n\to \infty$ and $p\to 0$ while keeping $np=m$ for some finite integer $m$. That brings you from the Binomial distribution to the Poisson distribution with parameter $m$ because
$$
P(X_n=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\approx\frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{np}{1-p}\right)^k(1-p)^n
\rightarrow\frac{m^k}{k!}e^{-m}.
$$
Then view this Poisson distribution with parameter $m$ as the result of summing $m$ independent Poisson random variables, each with parameter $1$. You can then use the central limit theorem to take $m\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [nice review](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2017/9-12-2017/p/baguiIMF9-12-2017.pdf) that lists four proofs: De Moivre's method using Stirling's formula to approximate the factorials in the binomial coefficient; a relatively new "method of ratios" and then the "method of moments" plus the CLT-based approach.

Comment: I see Section 3.1. Is there really no simpler way to show via this method?